# Update derived file to include changes from original file

Tags: linux, bash, version-control, diff, patch

Consider the following work flow:

1. File A is identical to file B
2. File B is modified
3. File A is modified

How can I update file B (programmatically) to include the changes in file A that are not in conflict with the changes made to file B in step 2?

---

I have looked at `diff` and `patch` but I could not figure out how to use them.

As an example: Let file A and file B in step 1 be:

```
KEYWA
 1 3 5

KEYWB
 3 3 3
```

Then file B is changed in step 2 to:

```
KEYWA
 1 3 5

KEYWB
 3 5 3
```

And finally file A is changed in step 3 to:

```
KEYWA
-- A comment
 1 3 5

KEYWB
 3 3 3
```

I would then like to update file B to include the changes in file A. Hence, I would like the new file B to become:

```
KEYWA
-- A comment
 1 3 5

KEYWB
 3 5 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure the reason behind whatever you're attempting.  Nevertheless, it appears that you're attempting to apply the diff of revision 2 of fileA and rev1 of the same file to rev2 of fileB.  Does that simplify the problem?

Comment: yes I think that is a good idea. Then I can generate a patch for changes made to file A and later apply that patch to file B?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

- After step 1: `cp A A2`
- In step 3: edit file A2 and leave file A unchanged
- After step 3 run:

  - `diff -u A A2 > patA`
  - `patch B <patA`